# Prove that function is integrable

Tags: integration

Prove that $$f(x)=1/x-[1/x], \ if \ x\neq 0,\ f(0)=0$$is integrable on $[0,1]$.

I'm not sure, but I think should be proved using the integral sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $0\le f(x)\le1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. The set of discontinuities of $f$ is $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, which has zero measure. By the Lebesgue integrability theorem, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

You can also compute the integral explicitly.
$$
f(x)=\frac1x-n\quad \text{on}\quad\Bigl(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac1n\Bigr].
$$
Then for any $N\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_N^1f(x)\,dx&=\sum_{n=1}^N\int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}\Bigl(\frac1x-n\Bigr)\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\Bigl((\log(n+1)-\log n-\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigr)\\
&=\log(N+1)-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align}$$
As $N\to\infty$, this converges to Eulers's $\gamma$.